# Unable to display obtained unix time in textView

Tags: android, android-layout, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building an app using firebase as my back-end.

I used **ServerValue.TIMESTAMP** & stored the unix time of a write operation in a variable named `timeStamp`.

I executed the below lines & there was a red line beneath `new SimpleDateFormat("H:mm",Locale.US);` and `format`.

The hovertext reads:

```
"Call requires API level 24 (current min is 15) android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat#SimpleDateFormat
```

This is my code in my RecyclerView.ViewHolder class:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("H:mm");
simpleDateFormat.format(timeStamp));
noticeTimeStampTextView.setText(simpleDateFormat);
```

Also after pressing on the run button I get this :

```
Error:(32, 32) error: no suitable method found for setText(SimpleDateFormat)
method TextView.setText(CharSequence) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; SimpleDateFormat cannot be converted to CharSequence)
method TextView.setText(int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; SimpleDateFormat cannot be converted to int)
```

**How should I fix this ?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use java.text.SimpleDateFormat instead of the Android one. That will work on the api level you're targeting. That along with passing a string to setText as mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your `SimpleDateFormat` to some object that `TextView.setText()` can understand.

Try `noticeTimeStampTextView.setText(simpleDateFormat.toString());`

Comment: After doing what you said I get this error - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/icu/text/SimpleDateFormat;

Comment: Are you working in Android Studio? Try running gradle build

Comment: Yes, I am using android studio & the project is building fine.
I got this error when I ran my app on my phone.
Also what are the reasons for the red lines as they still remain?

Comment: The error is saying that this method is only available on API level 24 or higher. Check this link: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels

Comment: Is your phone running Lollipop?

Comment: Yes my phone is running Lollipop

Comment: The link you have provided works fine & I do know what the error means but isn't SimpleDateFormat compatible for API versions below 24